# Bootstrap v5 responsive iframe not working, window too small image not responsive

Tags: object, iframe, responsive-design, embed, bootstrap-5

I spent several hours trying to embed a responsive svg image using an iframe or an object in Bootstrap v5.
Using this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <section id="about" class="about py-5 ">
        <div class="row align-items-center container py-5 mx-auto">
          <div class="text col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12">
           ...
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="100%"  src='https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/AJ_Digital_Camera.svg' allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the image seems not responsive and appears cut by a frame as shown below:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I also try to use `object` but still doesn't work.

Comment: The info you provide is insufficient to fully understand the problem and to give an accurate solution. Anyway, the .embed-responsive class must be combined with some of the classes which specify the aspect ratio. For example: embed-responsive-16by9. But all of this is fully supported on the 4.X version. For 5.X as today, you should consider the .ratio family of classes. Please see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/

Comment: @CristiánOrmazábal thanks, I have tried to used that classes but it still doesn't work, I will try to make a minimal example.